# Entity Framework MapToStoredProcedures Update and update not every fields of an object

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping

I have a `BaseEntity`:

```
public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

And a person entity:

```
public class People : BaseEntity
{ //Fields }
```

And I want to do Update, Insert, Delete with a stored procedure, so in my context do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
    .MapToStoredProcedures();
```

For don't update "CreatedOn" field, I override the `SaveChanges` as:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
 {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is IBaseEntity
                && (x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            IBaseEntity entity = entry.Entity as IBaseEntity;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreatedOn = now;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
                }                    
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But when do update, stored procedure will be run and set default value for `@createdOn` parameter and return exception.

How can I use `MapToStoredProcedures` and update not every column?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent people from changing the "CreatedOn" property? What is the exception? I think you may **have** to throw an exception if you determine that `.IsModified == true` or somehow get the existing entry and reset to the original value (large overhead and the danger of deadlocks if in a transaction). But you may want to use a database check constraint or something instead which will be better able to handle the desired situation. Alternatively tell EF the column is a `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` and have it default to GetDate() on Inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just let the database do the work of setting the value for you?

```
public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

And then your UPDATE procedure shouldn't even pass the parameter at all. Inside the UPDATE stored proc, set the value for CreatedOn to GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE(), or whatever sets a date value in your database if you're not using SQL Server.

Idea here is that setting the DatabaseGenerated option tells Entity Framework that it doesn't need to send that parameter to your procs because the database will generate the value for that column/property. You DO have to remember that the stored proc MUST return that column in its resultset -- but it can just use the default value for that column, that was generated in the proc.

If you do this, the override for SaveChanges to set the default value isn't even needed, the value will be set for you after the SaveChanges().

FYI: Entity Framework 6.x here.